# How can I restructure this MongoDB result into the right format?

Tags: node.js, object

I'm querying mongo with something like this:

```
  const loadedLists = await ListValues.find( {} )
```

I get results back that look more or less like this:

```
result = [ { listname: 'ListOne',
             values: [ {
                         label: 'OptOne',
                         cost: '25'
                        },{
                         label: 'OptTwo',
                         cost: '22'
                        }]
           }, { listname: 'ListTwo',
                values: [...//and so on]
          }]
```

I need to turn this into an object that looks like this:

```
 const newData = 
      { listOne: [ { label: 'OptOne', cost: '25' }, { label ...} ],
        listTwo: [ { label: 'OptTwo', cost: '25' }, { label ...} ]}
```

With the goal of eventually doing `Object.assign(res.locals, ...newData)` so `res.locals` has a property of `listOne` and `listTwo`.

I've messed around with map like this:

```
const hh = {}
hh = result.map( async list => {
  return { [list.listName]: list.values }
}
hh = await Promise.all(hh)
```

Which *almost* works, except hh looks like this:

```
[
  { listOne: [ ...//Properly has the values ] },
  { listTwo: [ ...//Same...]}
]
```

I just need to cleanly get those objects moved up a level. I've found NPM modules to do this, or loops to reprocess it, but I can't help but feel like there's a cleaner / tidier way to get it returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use reduce

```
const loadedLists = await ListValues.find( {} )
const hh = loadedList.reduce(
  (acc, {listname, values}) => (acc[listname] = values, acc)
  {}
)
```

Also you don't need to scatter `async` keyword all over the place. :) It makes sense to use it only with async functions that use `await` keyword.

Example from your code.

```
// why do you even need async here? there is nothing async in creating an object
hh = result.map( async list => {
  return { [list.listName]: list.values }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great! Thanks! I think async was left over from one of many attempts at doing it different ways. I'm nearly there... if I res.json(hh) or console.log(hh) it looks perfect, but when I try Object.assign(res.locals, ...hh) it says Undefined is Not a Function. Any idea why??

Comment: Ignore that.. I have no idea what I was trying to spread the result when I didn't need to... been trying too many different things for too long. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to accumulate the result.

```
'use strict';

let data = [{
  listname: 'ListOne',
  values: [{
    label: 'OptOne',
    cost: '25'
  }, {
    label: 'OptTwo',
    cost: '22'
  }]
}, {
  listname: 'ListTwo',
  values: [{
    label: 'OptOne',
    cost: '25'
  }, {
    label: 'OptTwo',
    cost: '22'
  }]
}];


let result = data.reduce(function (acc, {listname, values}) {
  if (acc[listname]) {
    acc[listname] = acc[listname].concat(values);
  } else {
    acc[listname] = values;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log('result', result);
```

This logs

> result { ListOne: 
>      [ { label: 'OptOne', cost: '25' },
>        { label: 'OptTwo', cost: '22' } ],
>     ListTwo: 
>      [ { label: 'OptOne', cost: '25' },
>        { label: 'OptTwo', cost: '22' } ] }